# How can I keep a value in a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with many entries, there are many selects that get their data from a table in mysql, that works fine, my form sends all the inputs to $_post just fine.  The problem is with the select portion.  The page loads info from a mysql table and populates all the fields with the exception of the select field.  The select field shows to the user a text name and passes a 2 digit number to the Post.  The problem is that when the page loads the Post for all the select fields is populated with the value of the first select object in the list.  So, in a nutshell all the (40) fields get overwritten when I submit.  Unless I go through all the dropdowns and set them back to the original settings they all change, not ideal.

```
echo "<tr><form action='update.php' method='post'>"; 
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";   
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$row['templatename']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='keyname1' value='".$row['keyname1']."'><readonly</td>";
    echo"<td></select><select name='lk1'>";
    while($rowA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $rowA['keytype'] . '">' . $rowA['keyname'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo"</select></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk1value' value='".$row['lk1value']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk1label' value='".$row['lk1label']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can mark an `<option>` element in a `<select>` list as the start/default value by using the `selected="selected"` attribute. When you are in the while loop and have checked that the current `$row` entry is the one the user has selected before, you can generate the output as follow:

```
while ($rowA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    if ($row['yourFieldInTheDatabase'] == $rowA['keytype']) {
        echo '<option value="'.$rowA['keytype'].'" selected="selected">'.$rowA['keyname'].'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$rowA['keytype'].'">'.$rowA['keyname'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm  maybe I wasn't clear on what I need, although that answer is close.  The field lk1 will already have data in it.  I need to show that data.  The select will already have bee populated from another page.  This page is a means for the user to "Edit" what they previously entered.  Right not the selected shows the last possible selectable value from the option values.

Comment: @EdLentz That's why the `selected="selected"` should only be printed for the row the user has selected, based on the values in the database. You have to add an `if` statement to check if the user has selected the current option or not. Depending on this check you output the attribute `selected="selected"` or not.

Comment: So I would use the if statement to determine whether they selected the field or not  How would that show what the original entry was when the page loads.  Not meaning to be dense, have a head cold and kinda foggy

Comment: @EdLentz I have edit my answer to include the while loop and if statement.